# Linux sed/awk : Replace the next line, after finding nth occurence of pattern match

Tags: sed

**File Content (Sample input):**

```
cat -n file.py | grep -i -C3 "# Create a zProv customer as well"
  1046              request.data['cn_cisco_origin'] = corp_nw.cn_cisco_origin
  1047              request.data['o_user'] = kv['o_user']
  1048
  1049              # Create a zProv customer as well
  1050              if is_production:
  1051                  if isolated_cloud:
  1052                      try:
--
  2774                  request.data['o_shared_vmanage_vbond'] = True
  2775                  request.data['o_user'] = kv['o_user']
  2776
  2777                  # Create a zProv customer as well
  2778                  if is_production:
  2779                      if isolated_cloud:
  2780                          try:
```

**What I want (Expected Output) :**

I want to replace `if is_production:` with `if is_staging:` after matching the pattern `# Create a zProv customer as well`

1st replaced sentence should begin with 14 spaces               `if is_staging:`

2nd replaced sentence should begin with 18 spaces                   `if is_staging:`

**What I tried:**

```
sed -i '/# Create a zProv customer as well/!b;n;c\              if is_staging:' file.py
```

It works fine for the 1st replacement. But it gives python indentation issue for the second replacement because the second occurence should begin with 18 spaces.

So I have to write sed command twice. The first command will be for 1st occurence with 14 spaces. The second command will be for 2nd occurence with 18 spaces.

I also tried the followings but it did not work:

```
sed -i '0,/# Create a zProv customer as well/{n;s/.*/\              if is_staging:/}' file.py
sed -i '1,/# Create a zProv customer as well/{n;s/.*/\              if is_staging:/}' file.py
sed -i '1s/# Create a zProv customer as well/{n;s/.*/\              if is_staging:/}' file.py
```

Comment: I don't understand- you say `I want to replace Next_Line with` but your same input (that first block of text under `File Content:` is your sample input, right?) doesn't contain `Next_Line`. You also say `Next_Line = "if is_production:"` so maybe you mean `Next_Line` as a placeholder in that first statement but then your sample input doesn't contain `if is_production:` either. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output and clear requirements so we can help you. See [ask].

Comment: @EdMorton Please find the edit. I made it easy to understand.

Comment: I didn't downvote and I have no way of knowing why anyone else downvoted but you didn't provide sample input/output that we could copy/paste to test with (a few lines of text for input, and that same few lines transformed as the output), instead you showed the output of a grep command running on a python file for input and a couple of separate lines of expected output, and you showed some code you tried but just said "it did not work" instead of telling us what actual problem you experienced running your code. Any of that could get you downvoted.

Comment: Also the input you posted has line numbers which we'd need to manually remove again to be able to use it as sample input. Just show us a text file you want to do something to as the sample input and then the modified version of that text file as the expected output. Given that, we can easily run a potential solution on the input and diff the output of that tool against the expected output and get an immediate pass/fail result. With sample input that isn't exactly like your real input and expected output that's just bits and pieces of your real expected output from that input we can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're saying boils down to that you want to match the indentation of the line following each `# Create a zProv customer as well` comment to the indentation of the comment itself.  And if so, then that's a more helpful way to characterize the issue than in terms of first / second / *etc*. matches to a pattern.  This is one way you could achieve that with a single `sed` command:

```
sed -i \
    -e '/^\s*# Create a zProv customer as well/ { p; N; s/#.*/if is_staging:/; }' \
    file.py
```

You will mostly recognize the pattern `/^\s*# Create a zProv customer as well/` from your own attempts.  Here I additionally ensure that the comment is preceded on its line only by whitespace, which is consistent with the example input presented, and which is important because that's the indentation that we will be reproducing.

Wherever that pattern is matched, `sed` will do the following:

- **`p`** - print the contents of the pattern space (that is, the comment line).
- **`N`** - append a newline and the next line of input to the pattern space.  This is to consume the next line, which we want to replace in whole, without losing track of the indentation level.
- **`s/#.*/if is_staging:/`** - substitute everything from the first `#` to the end of the line with the wanted replacement text *less any indentation*.  The indentation is carried over from the comment because the substitution starts at the `#`.

Comment: This solution works fine. Accepted the solution.

Comment: Note: a similar approach could do indentation-matching without modifying the original content of the following line, other than its indentation.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you're trying to do, using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    f { sub(/if is_production:/,"if is_staging:"); f=0 }
    /# Create a zProv customer as well/ { f=1 }
1' file.py
              request.data['cn_cisco_origin'] = corp_nw.cn_cisco_origin
              request.data['o_user'] = kv['o_user']

              # Create a zProv customer as well
              if is_staging:
                  if isolated_cloud:
                      try:

                  request.data['o_shared_vmanage_vbond'] = True
                  request.data['o_user'] = kv['o_user']

                  # Create a zProv customer as well
                  if is_staging:
                      if isolated_cloud:
                          try:
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file.py
              request.data['cn_cisco_origin'] = corp_nw.cn_cisco_origin
              request.data['o_user'] = kv['o_user']

              # Create a zProv customer as well
              if is_production:
                  if isolated_cloud:
                      try:

                  request.data['o_shared_vmanage_vbond'] = True
                  request.data['o_user'] = kv['o_user']

                  # Create a zProv customer as well
                  if is_production:
                      if isolated_cloud:
                          try:
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/# Create a zProv customer as well/{
        :a;n;s/^(.* )if is_production:.*/\1if is_staging:/;t;ba}' file
```

Match `# Create a zProv customer as well`.

Print the current line and fetch the next until a match of `if is_production:` then replace that string with `if is_staging:`.